# C# ConvertToDouble string 5.5

Tags: c#, строки

К примеру есть строка "5.5" , пытаюсь с этой строки записать число 5.5 в переменную double , но пишет "Input string was not in a correct format" , хотя пробуя строку с целым числом 5 , всё отлично работает, как записать со строки "5.5" в переменную double ?

```
string ss = "5.5";
double dd1 = Convert.ToDouble(ss);
double dd2 = double.Parse(ss); // так же не работает
```

P.S. нужно именно когда "5.5" с "5,5" сработает отлично и запишет число 5,5 , но возможно ли имея строку 5.5 записать данное число в double как 5,5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Convert.ToDouble](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

```
double dd1 = Convert.ToDouble(ss, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[double.Parse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

```
double dd2 = double.Parse(ss, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: отлично , работает, так же нашел ещё мини способ c Replace('.', ',')

Comment: @hekeemje `Replace` это всё же кустарщина какая-то, лучше стандартными штуками пользоваться